# How to animate negative margin only

Tags: javascript, css

I have this

```
ul{
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms linear;
    transition: all 1000ms linear;
}
```

Then with javascript, amongst other things

```
let px = 295 // increments through other things
document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.marginLeft = `-${px}px`;
```

Then the `ul` comes back to `margin-left:0`, but I want it to animate on negative margin and just snap on `margin-left:0`

edit:

The first answer sounds as though I'm not clear. I want to click on an element and have it animate one way, and then snap back to the default position. The usual  transitions animate both ways

Answer (score -1):

Try to use class for animation and use jQuery to manage these classes

Take a look at my example

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('ul').toggleClass('animated');
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin-left: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 1000ms linear;
  transition: margin 1000ms linear;
}

ul.animated {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>

<button>Animate</button>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. Run your demo and click `Animation` twice. The second time I need it to snap without animation

Comment: consider to use `jQuery animate()` @relidon

Comment: I'm looking for a pure js method, for the sake of learning if nothing else